# XML: Why can't I use a different namespace?

Tags: xml, browser, xml-namespaces, w3c

As far as i know, namespaces URI are not accessed, but only represents any name chosen by you in order to avoid name conflicts. So why the following W3C example stop working if I change the namespace?

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Does the browser uses the URI string to compare with some other stored in it to know that it is a XML file?

Comment: This is not a "W3C example". W3Schools (*w3schools.com*) has nothing to do with the W3C (*w3.org*).

Comment: You are explaining that it prevents name conflicts. but then why do you wonder that this mechanism actually works (different name → different meaning/function)?

Comment: What do you mean, it "stops working". Never tell us something "doesn't work", tell us how it fails.

Comment: @unor I don't know if I got your observation, but, for me, it prevents name conflicts letting different SEQUENCES OF STRINGS for each element; just that. It shouldn't mean anything.

Comment: @MichaelKay Sorry. What I mean with "stop working" is: the XML is not showed anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespaces work like last names in people. You can have two people with the same first name. You need the last name to distinguish them.

You can have two XML nodes with the same local name (like `<stylesheet>`), when they are in two different namespaces they are *completely different nodes* and anything that processes XML will recognize the difference. <sup>(*)</sup>

This is nothing special for XML, this is how namespaces work everywhere. In most programming languages you can have two different functions with the same name, when they are in different namespaces the compiler can tell them apart.

So I'm not sure why you're surprised that changing the namespace changes the meaning of the XML.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> XSLT processors work with `<stylesheet>` (and a couple of other) elements that are in the `"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` namespace, specifically. Any elements with the name `stylesheet` that are in a different namespace are ignored, you are free to use them for your own purposes. That's the whole point, after all.

Comment: So, you are saying that the processor only see the <stylesheet> element as a XSL element if it's namespace is strictly equals to "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" ? Like, it checks this string first to see if it corresponds to a XSL namespace,and then processes the right elements as XSL elements?

Comment: Yes. Why is that so surprising? (It seems to me that you think that namespaces are "just an attribute".  They are not. They are an actual, physical part of the node name. They appear in attribute form so you don't always have to write them out very single time.)

Comment: Not that surprising. I just thought that namespaces were free-choice like; that the processor would just use it to make distinctions about elements, not inside it's processing operations.

Comment: But a different namespace means that it is a different node. As in, not at all alike. In any other environment (say, C#) you wouldn't expect that you can't freely invent namespaces without throwing the compiler off track, so why would it be any different with XML? Namespaces serve the exact same purpose there, of course they behave exactly the same.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. So, I can use free namespaces to distinct elements, but this namespaces won't be recognized by the processor to an specific operation; but some namespaces (like the XML one) will...right?

Comment: If it helps, think of them as colors. `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` is green. The XSLT processor recognizes green nodes as instructions. It can read all other nodes, but it does not see them as instructions. This way you can mix XSLT instructions and other XML without confusing the XSLT processor. It's like syntax highlighting in your favorite editor. Your brain won't consider the word "function" as special if it's inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is a processor used to execute XSL, and the namespace in your case is the "basic" XSL namespace, if it's a wrong URI, then the processor don't know which XSL version you will be using to apply transformation.